# Unit Root Test seems ambiguous - is my time series stationary?

Tags: regression, residuals, stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am testing the stationarity of my residuals through the ADF test (Augmented Dickey Fuller test) and the results imply stationarity of my time series. However, the time series do not really show complete stationarity and rather implies a structural break. I am not really sure how to handle this now.

The time series of my residuals looks similar like the following:

[image]

Is there any stationarity of my time series? I am doubtful about the change of the structure in the second half (less fluctuating residuals).

Comment: The variance significantly changes after some point as you've also mentioned. At least, this plot wouldn't be a good example of a stationary process.

Comment: Try Perron's unit root test for series with a known structural break date, or the Zivot-Andrews sup-Wald unit root test for series with possible structural break (date unknown).